# How to create 2 connections (mysql and postgresql) with Doctrine2 in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm new to Symfony2. And my question quite simple.
I would use 2 connections to DB at different host and driver in one bundle.

Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: alpha
        connections:
            alpha:
                driver:     pdo_mysql
                host:       localhost
                dbname:     alpha
                user:       root
                charset:    UTF8
            beta:
                driver:     pdo_pgsql
                host:       localhost
                dbname:     beta
                user:       root
                charset:    UTF8
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        entity_managers:
            alpha:
                connection: alpha
            beta:
                connection: beta
```

You see, we declare two connections in the `dbal` section and two entity managers in the `orm` one.

After that, you can use both:

```
$emAlpha = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager('alpha');
$emBeta  = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager('beta');
```

As the `alpha` one was defined as the default one, you can access it without specifying its name:

```
$emAlpha = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
```

Comment: Thanks! But if i will use some database only in read mode, setter methods in entity classes are necessary to use?

Comment: Need I to specify field types in entity classes for existing database (which in read only mode)?

Comment: Yes because Doctrine need this informations to correctly hydrate your entities...