# Use a postgres database with symfony3

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

We are retro-engineering a web application using a postgres database. We want to refactor the code using the symfony framework but we are facing a problem to use the database with it.

For the moment our project is working with a MySQL database just using the same structure for the used tables. The problem is that, now, we need to use the postgresql database because there is a lot of data and it's not really adapted to MySQL as far as we know.

We made a lot of research but we didn't succeed to create a postgresql database in the symfony project. 

First, we tried to apply this tutorial : http://www.tutodidacte.com/symfony2-utiliser-une-base-de-donnee-postgresql we adapted it as much as possible for our project.
Here is our  **config.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
#     http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
         #      http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:       "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~

# Twig Configuration
twig:
     debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
     strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
           #Mysql
           default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
           #Postgresql
           pgsql:
                driver:   pdo_pgsql
                host:     localhost
                port:     5432
                dbname:   "%psql_database_name%"
                user:     root
                password: "%psql_database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8

         #mapping_types:
            #geometry: string

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        #naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        #auto_mapping: true

        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default

                 # lister les Bundles utilisant la connexion par defaut

                 #mappings:
                    #monprojetmysqlBundle:  ~
                    #tutoUserBundle:  ~

            pgsql:
                connection: pgsql    # connection name for your additional DB

                # bundles utilisant la connexion Postgresql
                #mappings:
                    # PostgresqlBundle: ~

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

but when we launched this command : **php bin/console     doctrine:database:create --connection=pgsql** we had this answer :

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]              
    An exception occured in driver: could not find driver  



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]  
   could not find driver                



  [PDOException]         
   could not find driver  


doctrine:database:create [--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

It seems that we don't have the module **pdo_pgsql** so we searched how to install it.

 To do it, we applied the script proposed on this github page : https://gist.github.com/doole/8651341#file-install_psql_php-sh 

 We changed the version of postgres.app to 9.5.
After a few tries, we finally succeeded to have **pdo_pgsql**  on the result of **php -m**.

 But know, we have this answer when we launch the command : **php bin/console doctrine:database:create --connection=pgsql**

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_pgsql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pgsql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0


  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]              
  An exception occured in driver: could not find driver  



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]  
  could not find driver                



  [PDOException]         
   could not find driver  


doctrine:database:create [--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

We tried to do this : [Install PHP with Postgresql on MAC using homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706027/install-php-with-postgresql-on-mac-using-homebrew)
but it didn't change anything. Now we have 5 PHP WARNING for pdo_pgsql and pgsql when we launch the command **php bin/console doctrine:database:create --connection=pgsql**

We have also seen this : 
[How to change a database to postgresql with Symfony 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588646/how-to-change-a-database-to-postgresql-with-symfony-2-0) and this : [How to create 2 connections (mysql and postgresql) with Doctrine2 in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440403/how-to-create-2-connections-mysql-and-postgresql-with-doctrine2-in-symfony2) but it didn't really help because the first one concern debian and we are working on OS X El Capitan and the second one don't tell more than the previous tutorial.

Finally, the only hope we have is that someone can help us...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does the `WARNING for pdo_pgsql` say? Did you verify that you've properly installed the pdo-pgsql module (by looking at the `phpinfo()` output - be aware that the php-config might differ for CLI and Server)?

Comment: `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_pgsql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pgsql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: This is still the same warning but we have it 5 times. I found that with all the  command I used, I reinstall php and now I have 2 php.ini. I will try to remove everything completely and reinstall php with `brew install php56 --with-postgresql`

Comment: It worked. I delete every php files and reinstall it with brew and now it works. I'll be more specific during the day. Thank you fateddy

Comment: Glad you could figure it out!

Comment: For me, WAMPServer was using a different version of php for the CLI, so I had to adjust its .ini manually.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I fixed it by removing all the files that manage php and reinstalling php with homebrew.

---- Removing php ---- 

 First, I used the following command from root (`cd /`) to find all the files starting by "php"

```
find . -name "php*"
```

Depending on the results (you might have a lot), remove all the files that need to be removed (at this point it's your judgement that matter). For example, I removed files in /usr/local and /usr/bin but not in /Applications or /Homebrew.

 Examples :

```
rm -Rf /usr/bin/php*
rm -Rf /usr/local/php*
```

Sometimes, you can have a "permission denied" error even with sudo but it didn't make problem at the end.

---- Reinstalling php ----

Once everything concerning php is removed, you can reinstall it using the following command line :

```
brew install php56 --with-postgresql
```

If you have a "libz not found" error, you will need to launch the following command :

```
xcode-select --install
```

and relaunch the installation with :

```
brew reinstall php56 --with-postgresql
```

If everything went well, you will only have to define the field `date.timezone` in php.ini and you will have new php system. You can check that you have the pdo_pgsql module installed using this commande line : `php -m`.

---- Connect your database to your symfony project ----

First, you need to modify the file app/config/parameters.yml in your project by adding the following code :

```
# Postgresl
    psql_database_driver: pdo_pgsql
    psql_database_host: 127.0.0.1
    psql_database_port: 5432
    psql_database_name: your_database_name
    psql_database_user: your_user_name
    psql_database_password: your_password
```

The fields host and port can be different but this two are the default values for symfony and a postgres database.

Then, you will have to modify the file app/config/config.yml at the Doctrine Configuration level this way :

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: pgsql
        connections:
           #Mysql
           default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
           #Postgresql
           pgsql:
                driver:   pdo_pgsql
                host:     "%psql_database_host%"
                port:     "%psql_database_port%"
                dbname:   "%psql_database_name%"
                user:     "%psql_database_user%"
                password: "%psql_database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8

        #mapping_types:
            #geometry: string

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

This is an example you can adapt as you wish.

Now, you can connect your database to your project with this command line :

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create --connection=pgsql
```

If you already have entities in your src/AppBundle/Entity you can create your tables with :

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Everything must be alright now. I hope, it will help someone else who faces this kind of problems.